# Printing a loop to a single label control in WIndows forms

Tags: c#

How to print each factorial from 1-20 using a for loop?

The output should be to the same label in a Windows forms application.

I tried using this and I didn't get what I wanted (which is printing vertically all the factorials from 1 through 20 i.e(2,6,24,) ), instead I see a value  of -2102162736

```
private void nFactorial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   long facOut, factorial;
   long num = 20;
   factorial = num;

   for (facOut = num - 1; facOut >= 1; facOut--)
   {
       factorial *= facOut;         
       nFactorial.Text += factorial.ToString();  
   }
}
```

Comment: you have said "didn't get what i wanted". It would be useful if you could fully describe what your desired output was and what you are actually getting. This will aid us in determining the issue

Comment: `int` is not large enough to hold factorial of 20. you need to use `long`.

Comment: @PaulMarshall   I have stated the desired output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
nFactorial.Text = factorial.ToString();
```

You are overwriting nFactorial each loop iteration.

What you want (I assume) is to append the text, so you'd want to do something like this (format how you'd like):

```
nFactorial.Text += factorial.ToString() + Environment.NewLine; // Environment.NewLine to display each value on a separate line, again format how you'd like
```

Note, as  Selman Genç mentioned, you need to use `long` instead of `int` (change `Int32` to long):

```
long facOut, factorial, number;
long num = 20;
```

Putting it all together:

```
private void nFactorial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long facOut, factorial, number;
    long num = 20;
    factorial = num;

    for (facOut = num - 1; facOut >= 1; facOut--)
    {
       factorial *= facOut;         
       nFactorial.Text += factorial.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;  
    }
}
```

Edit:  Ok, you are looping backwards.  You need to work up not down.  Try this:

```
private void nFactorial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long facOut, factorial;
    long num = 20;
    factorial = 1;

    for (facOut = 1; facOut <= num; facOut++)
    {
        factorial *= facOut;
        tb.Text += factorial.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Note: if you want to skip 1, set `facOut = 2` in the `for` loop.

Comment: still not giving the desired output (which is printing vertically all the factorials from 1 through 20), instead I see a somewhat random set of numbers

Comment: @OkekeDavid I edited my answer.  Please see the last sentence.

Comment: I updated the question because of the tip I got from @PaulMarsall . I changed it to long  and still no change.

Comment: @OkekeDavid `-2102162736` is the value you get when you use int, I think updating **all** variable types to `long` should fix your issue.

Comment: changing the variable types to  long and adding the "+="  gives a really long value ,

Comment: Did you use `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: I did , now it outputs to new lines but the values aren't correct (very random)

Comment: In your question, please show what the desired output should be vs the actual output you get. For example, my first line is `380` which is `20*19`, is this this what you are expecting?  My last line is the value of `20!` which appears to be your desired outcome.

Comment: @OkekeDavid, ok, thank you for providing the desired output, now I understand your problem.  Please see my edit.